# Android service asyncrounous: How to make sure that connection is established before running onStartCommand

Tags: android, service

I have class what creates connection to *google play service*, when connection is established `onConnectedToGooglePlayService()` is called. When new `mySerivce` is started, first thing is to establish connection to *play service* as you can see in the code.

The problem is that connecting to *play service* takes some time and I can't be sure that connection is established when `onStartCommand` is called and I can't get info from Intent.

So my question is: What is the best way to handle this situation? I thought of  creating a global variable and processing intent when connection is established, but I am not sure that's the right way to do this.

```
public class myService extends Service implements ConnectedToGooglePlayService {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new ConnectToGooglePlayService(this, this).connect();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectedToGooglePlayService(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to  achieve. Ensure that code in `onStartCommand` is not executed until `onConnectedToGooglePlayService` was called?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Service` binding is an asynchronous process, the cleanest way to pause execution of the code is to block execution of the entire thread, and resume it once the `Service` is connected.

However, `onStartCommand()` is called on UI thread and it's not a good idea to block it, therefore you have to offload the work to a background thread. If you don't need parallel execution, then `IntentService` will suffice. But the most general approach is something along these lines:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements ConnectedToGooglePlayService {

    private final Object MONITOR = new Object();

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new ConnectToGooglePlayService(this, this).connect();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // this block of code "pauses" the thread until mGoogleApiClient is not null
                synchronized (MONITOR) {
                    while (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        try {
                            MONITOR.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                // do some stuff that require google API client 

            }
        }).start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectedToGooglePlayService(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
        synchronized (MONITOR) {
            this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
            MONITOR.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

One thing I noticed though, is that you don't account for the possibility of remote `Service` being disconnected unexpectedly. I don't know what your reliability requirements are, but it could lead to some bizzare bugs.

I wrote a blog post about bound IPC services which might be helpful to you: [How to establish a reliable (crash and kill tolerant) connection to bound IPC (e.g. AIDL) Service in Android](http://www.techyourchance.com/reliable-connection-to-bound-ipc-service-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to @override onStartCommand on a service neither to use GoogleApiClient as a global variable a better aproach would be :

```
public class myService extends Service  {

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

         new ConnectToGooglePlayService(this, new ConnectToGooglePlayService(this, new ConnectedToGooglePlayService(){
         @Override
         public void onConnectedToGooglePlayService(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
            // you can access the on start command parameters because you
            // set the variables to be unchangeable by using the word final
         }
         }).connect();

         return super.onStartCommand(final intent, flags, startId);
   }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well in that case simply do as the modified code (asuming the second parameter is ConnectToGooglePlayService)

Comment: And one more thing if you want to send data to your activity don't link them with an interface. It will crash when activity is destroyed and it becomes null, use a broadcast receiver -> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm

Answer (score -1):

See if it works.

```
public class myService extends Service implements ConnectedToGooglePlayService {
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new ConnectToGooglePlayService(this, this).connect();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        while(mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Log.d("mGoogleApiClient status", "connecting...");
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onConnectedToGooglePlayService(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
}

}
```

Comment: That is good solution, but what happens when Activity is destroyed?

Comment: You'll have to implement this interface every classes where you want to start this service. Since you'll be initiating the constructor every time, only that class's googlePlayServiceConnected method should be called.

Comment: I noticed that you are trying to start service by calling yourService.start(); but this doesn't work cause service is started with Intent and by callins startService()

Comment: Isn't this wast of processor power. There should be more intelligent way to handle this?

Comment: Processor power wise? Not much. Sure its dumb intelligence wise. But as for prior solution, since service has its own context to work out its stuffs, we can't  pass an interface reference(implemented by Activity) from activity to service.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!